# Compute the derivative of $S(x) = \int_1^{\arcsin(x)}\frac{\sin(t)}{t}dt$

Tags: calculus, integration

My book states the following:

---

*FUNDAMENTAL THEOREM OF CALCULUS*. Assume the function $f$ is continous in $x\in[a,b].$ Put $$S(x)=\int_a^xf(t)dt, \quad a\leq x\leq b.$$

Then, it follows that the function $S$ is differentiable in $x\in(a,b)$ with the derivative

$$S'(x)=f(x), \quad a<x<b.$$

---

Using this on my integral, I get

$$S'(x) = \left(\int_1^{\arcsin(x)}\frac{\sin(t)}{t}dt\right)'=\frac{\sin(\arcsin(x))}{\arcsin(x)} =\frac{x}{\arcsin(x)}.$$

This is wrong. I don't see in the theorem what they're doing with $a$.

Comment: Because your $S(x)$ is not the same $S(x)$ in the theorem. What you call $S$ should actually be $G=S\circ \arcsin $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the fundamental theorem of calculus you have that $\int^{g(x)}_c f(t)\,\mathrm dt=F(g(x))-F(c)$, but $[F(g(x))-F(c)]'=f(g(x))g'(x)\neq f(g(x))$.

---

As @Xander pointed out its possible that the OP doesnt knows yet the second part of the FTC. So, using just the stated FTC in the question we have that

$$H(g(x))=\int_c^{g(x)}f(t)\,\mathrm dt\implies [H(g(x))]'=H'(g(x))g'(x)$$

from the chain rule. And after notice that by definition $H(x)=\int_c^x f(t)\,\mathrm dt$, thus $H'(x)=f(x)$, so $H'(g(x))=f(g(x))$.

Comment: Ah... okay now I see! Thank you!

Comment: While this is true, the usual approach is to the fundamental theorem of calculus (FTC) is to first prove the version given by the OP, then use that to prove the result that you are invoking.  It seems somewhat circular to use the second part of the FTC to justify something that is a vital part of understanding the first part of the FTC, and which can be shown via more elementary arguments.

Comment: @XanderHenderson well, I assumed that the OP knows this second part of the fundamental theorem of calculus. In general questions as that the OP are not introduced before to show and prove the two parts of the FTC.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:**

Let $y(x)=\arcsin(x)$ and use the chain rule $$\frac{dS(y(x))}{dx}=\frac{dS(y(x))}{dy(x)}\frac{dy(x)}{dx}$$

Answer (score 0):

If
$$ F(x) = \int_{1}^{x} \frac{\sin(t)}{t} \,\mathrm{d}t, $$
then you are being asked to find $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} F(\arcsin(x))$.  First, we note that the fundamental theorem of calculus implies that
$$ F'(x) = \frac{\sin(x)}{x}. $$
We'll use this in the computation below.  Next, by the chain rule, we obtain
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} F(\arcsin(x))
&= F'(\arcsin(x))\cdot  \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \arcsin(x) \\
&= \frac{\sin(\arcsin(x))}{\arcsin(x)} \cdot  \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \arcsin(x) && \text{(by FTC)} \\
&= \frac{\sin(\arcsin(x))}{\arcsin(x)} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} && \text{(derivative of arcsin}) \\
&= \frac{x}{\arcsin(x)} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} && \text{($\sin(\arcsin(t)) = 
t\ \forall t$)} \\
&= \frac{x}{\arcsin(x)\sqrt{1-x^2}}.
\end{align}

---

EDITED to address a different question:

The fundamental theorem of calculus states that if $a$ is *any* real number, $f$ is "sufficiently nice" (essentially, $f$ must be integrable), and $F$ is the function defined on $\mathbb{R}$ by the integral
$$ F(x) = \int_{a}^{x} f(x) \,\mathrm{d}x, $$
then $F'(x) = f(x)$.  There is no actual dependence on $a$ in the theorem.  To see why this must be true, suppose that $a' \in \mathbb{R}$ is *another* real number, i.e. suppose that $a'\ne a$.  Then it follows from the linearity of the integral that
$$ \int_{a'}^{x} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x
= \underbrace{\int_{a'}^{a} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x}_{=:C} + \int_{a}^{x} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x
= \int_{a}^{x} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x + C,
$$
where $C$ is a definite integral, and so equal to some constant (presuming, of course, that all of these integrals exist).  Differentiating, we obtain
$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \left[ \int_{a'}^{x} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x \right]
= \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \left[ \int_{a}^{x} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x + C \right]
= \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \left[ \int_{a}^{x} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x \right],
$$
since the differentiation is a linear operator, and the derivative of a constant is zero.  In particular,
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \left[ \int_{a'}^{x} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x \right]
= \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \left[ \int_{a}^{x} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x \right]
= F'(x),
$$
independent of the choice of $a$ (and/or $a'$).

Comment: @MarkViola I've changed the notation so that it can't possible conflict with the OP's inconsistent notation.

Comment: Ok sorry for not specifying this in my post, but I do know the chainrule and such, what I'm interested to know is what happens to $a$.

Comment: @Parseval If the question is about the lower limit of integration, and not the application of the chain rule, then you may want to correct your question so that the errors introduced by not applying the chain rule correctly don't cause confusion about what your question actually is...